# gsub "#" is returning "\#" instead of "#"

Tags: ruby, gsub

I'm trying to turn "${variablename}" into "#{variablename}" so it can access the variable in the string.

for instance, if I have a variable foo = "bar", I want "${foo}".gsub("$", "#") to return "bar" because I'm expecting "#{foo}" which is "bar", but instead I'm getting "\#{foo}"

open up irb and try this

```
"${Hello}".gsub("$","#")
```

=> "\#{Hello}"

I want it to be "#{Hello}"

Can somebody help?? I hope my question is clear..

Comment: You're getting what you want. Try `puts "${Hello}".gsub("$","#")`.

Comment: To further show it's not gsub, evaluate the simple expressions `"#hi"` and examine the output. This behavior is because IRB will display the result of [`theResult.inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-inspect) if it can: "Returns a string containing a *human-readable representation* of obj."

Answer (score 3):

That is just irb escaping things for rendering. It's doing exactly what you want it to do already.

That said, Just producing the string `#{foo}` isn't going to perform string interpolation for you. Strings aren't suddenly interpolated the second they contain a `#{}`.

You should rethink your code so your values are stored in a hash, not as local variables.